# when executing docker-compose, Service 'web' failed to build

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker-compose, dockerfile

I get this message in the terminal when I run docker-compose, everything looks good as far as my novice eyes can tell.

```
$ docker-compose up
Building web
[+] Building 9.3s (8/9)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                            0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                                                                             0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                               0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.8                                                                                                                                   0.7s 
 => [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.8@sha256:883e00aeb53d4cecb6842f2e10078a6bc8faf5dbb3d8b2a77cb1a232d81bf7ca                                                                             0.0s 
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                               0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 4.06kB                                                                                                                                                             0.0s 
 => CACHED [2/5] WORKDIR /gekkopedia                                                                                                                                                            0.0s 
 => CACHED [3/5] COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /gekkopedia/                                                                                                                                         0.0s 
 => ERROR [4/5] RUN pip install pipenv && pip install --system                                                                                                                                  8.5s 
------
 > [4/5] RUN pip install pipenv && pip install --system:
#8 1.827 Collecting pipenv
#8 2.014   Downloading pipenv-2022.7.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.7 MB)
#8 3.354      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.7/3.7 MB 2.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#8 3.380 Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=36.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pipenv) (57.5.0)
#8 3.426 Collecting certifi
#8 3.446   Downloading certifi-2022.6.15-py3-none-any.whl (160 kB)
#8 3.488      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 160.2/160.2 KB 3.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#8 3.643 Collecting virtualenv
#8 3.667   Downloading virtualenv-20.15.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10.1 MB)
#8 5.486      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 10.1/10.1 MB 5.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#8 5.497 Requirement already satisfied: pip>=22.0.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pipenv) (22.0.4)
#8 5.538 Collecting virtualenv-clone>=0.2.5
#8 5.556   Downloading virtualenv_clone-0.5.7-py3-none-any.whl (6.6 kB)
#8 5.621 Collecting platformdirs<3,>=2
#8 5.641   Downloading platformdirs-2.5.2-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
#8 5.692 Collecting six<2,>=1.9.0
#8 5.714   Downloading six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
#8 5.765 Collecting filelock<4,>=3.2
#8 5.786   Downloading filelock-3.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
#8 5.827 Collecting distlib<1,>=0.3.1
#8 5.846   Downloading distlib-0.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (461 kB)
#8 5.923      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 461.2/461.2 KB 6.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#8 6.036 Installing collected packages: distlib, virtualenv-clone, six, platformdirs, filelock, certifi, virtualenv, pipenv
#8 7.777 Successfully installed certifi-2022.6.15 distlib-0.3.4 filelock-3.7.1 pipenv-2022.7.4 platformdirs-2.5.2 six-1.16.0 virtualenv-20.15.1 virtualenv-clone-0.5.7
#8 7.778 WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: 
https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
#8 7.940 WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.1.2 is available.
#8 7.940 You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
#8 8.322
#8 8.322 Usage:
#8 8.322   pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
#8 8.322   pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
#8 8.322   pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
#8 8.322   pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
#8 8.322   pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...
#8 8.322
#8 8.322 no such option: --system
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install pipenv && pip install --system]: exit code: 2
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build : Build failed

geeks@DESKTOP-J1GH5BH MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Gekkonidae/gekkopedia
$ ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build : Build failed
bash: ERROR:: command not found

geeks@DESKTOP-J1GH5BH MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Gekkonidae/gekkopedia
$ ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build : Build failed
bash: ERROR:: command not found

geeks@DESKTOP-J1GH5BH MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Gekkonidae/gekkopedia
$ ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build : Build failed
bash: ERROR:: command not found
```

this is my docker-compose, this is the first time I have attempted to use postgres with Docker as well as the first I have tried anything but SQLite with Django.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /gekkopedia/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes: 
      - .:/gekkopedia
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:14
    volumes: 
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/Postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"
         
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

This is my Dockerfile, not surte about trying to upgrade pip in the dependencies

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.8

# Set enviroment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /gekkopedia 

# Install dependencies
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /gekkopedia/
RUN pip install pipenv && pip install --system 

# Copy project 
COPY . /gekkopedia/
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you please [edit] your question and copy-paste the `requirements.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

In the Dockerfile, I think it should be:

```
...
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install
...
```